# Explain the verb tense in "I wish I never woke up this morning"

Tags: verbs, tenses, modal-verbs

This is from a song by Police, [*Darkness*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8qntH9HKq0A):

> "I can dream up schemes when I'm sitting in my seat
>   I don't see any flaws 'til I get to my feet
>   I wish I never woke up this morning
>   Life was easy when it was boring"

Shouldn't it be, according to [www.eslbase.com](http://www.eslbase.com/grammar/wish), "I wish I  <strike>havn't</strike>   hadn't woken up this morning"?
(though I agree the latter flows worse)

Comment: For some reason I am reminded of the lyrics:

    Wish I knew what you were looking for
    Might have known what you would find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, by the rules of grammar, it should be

> I wish I'd never woken up this morning.

But if you Google "I wish I never" you find that lots of people use constructions like

> I wish I never woke up this morning.

For example:

> I wish I never told you,
>   I wish I never met you,
>   I wish I never ever got drunk that night.

So, while strictly speaking this should probably be called bad grammar, it is nevertheless a quite common usage.

Comment: As mentioned by Kosmonaut and JSBangs, the replacement of subjunctive "were" with the past tense "was" becomes more common http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/when-should-i-use-the-subjunctive-mood and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19418/speculative-conditional-why-does-it-use-the-past-tense-or-past-perfect-tense

Answer (score 3):

It should be **I wish I'd never woken up this morning**, but Sting usually sings in a fairly "clipped" manner, so he'd naturally drop the **'d** and **n**. It helps the song sound "streetwise".

(that's a shortened *wish I had not ever...*. OP's *wish I haven't...* is worse than Sting's version).

I don't know if Sting wrote the lyrics, but even if he didn't, I imagine he could have changed it if he wanted. I think he was originally a teacher, so he wouldn't have done it out of ignorance. But I guess we can allow him to be "off-duty" from that when he's working in his second career.

Comment: right, I meant "had", not "have"

Comment: "I wish I'd never woken up this morning" fits on two lyrics lines -so he simplified it

Comment: Do you not have enough rep to edit your incorrect version then? I thought anyone could edit their own question text. Anyway, I really don't think you're going to learn much about the English language by studying popular song lyrics. It's not even a good source of "common speech", let alone "correct or careful speech".

Comment: Isn't this essentially a UK-US difference? As a UK speaker, I agree that the most common form would be "I wish I'd never...", but as I understand, "I wish I never..." is common US usage. Cf. "Have you ever smoked?" vs "Did you ever smoke?"

Comment: @Neil Coffey: I don't think it's particularly different either side of the pond. When I said "should be" in my answer, I didn't mean to imply criticism of the wording. But OP seemed to be looking for the nearest equivalent "grammatically impeccable" phrasing, so that's what I tried to provide.

Comment: Though of course, intrinsically there's nothing more "grammatically impeccable" about either of the two choices (some languages don't even make this distinction at all): it's just a matter of preference/general use/etiquette.

Answer (score 1):

The grammar of wishing is very complex for non-native learners of English, and depends on variables such as if the wish is for the past, present or future and if the wish relates to something the wisher has control over or not.

Using the Sting's example we have:

```
Past: I wish had never woken up this morning.

Present: I wish I didn't wake up (tired) every morning.

Future: I wish I would not wake up tomorrow. ??
```

The last wish is more likely to be expressed as a hope:

```
I hope I don't wake up tomorrow.
```

(I agree that pop lyrics are an unreliable guide to standard English grammar.)

Comment: yes but the lyrics are catchy-they stuck in your mind. So it may be worthwhile to analyze as a starting point

Answer (score -1):

The correct sentence should have been "I wish I *had* never woke up this morning." Using "never" in this sentence would still have been grammatically correct. It's a correct method of negation. But the original sentence is missing *had*, which is necessarily in this case.

Comment: but past perfect is had+past participle. The past participle of "wake" is woken, not woke