# “Would not have” + past participle in a real reflection

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, conditionals

Here is the situation:

1. If there had been an apple, I wouldn’t have eaten it.

...is understood to mean:

2. There wasn’t an apple; I therefore didn’t eat it.

Building on this, can we use the imaginary negative result of *wouldn’t
have eaten it* in the hypothetical situation **without** the opposite
being fulfilled?

(The opposite would be *I have eaten it*, but this is
illogical because there wasn’t any apple.)

In other words, this situation:

3. If I had not been interested in science, I wouldn’t have done all of that.

...is understood to mean:

4. I was interested in science, and I have done a lot of things.

Accordingly, in the real situation, the result is the opposite of the
hypothetical one.

So could *wouldn’t have +PAST PARTICPLE* be used in both cases, both
the “imaginary negative result” and the “opposite of the real
case result”?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Speculative conditional: Why does it use the past tense or past perfect tense?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19418/speculative-conditional-why-does-it-use-the-past-tense-or-past-perfect-tense)